# PHP Good practices - Methods with too many parameters

Tags: php, search, methods, parameters, arguments

I've made a class and method just for search things on my website. It has too many parameters, the search parameters. My controller grabs data from forms and then pass to the model.

```
public function search($name, $age, $foo, ... $bar, $lorem) {
```

Are there any tips of this kind of method? Maybe a good practice about method with too much parameters.
Thanks.

EDIT:

parameters are for the search...
$name should search people with value of $name
$age should search people with value of $age
and so on...
something like the SQL Where clause.

Thanks again.

Comment: Pass a single array which contains each parameter as an array element.

Comment: @MarcB: Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: Usually this is an indicator that the method is too complex/powerful. You should break the functionality down.

Comment: There's no silver bullet for this. It's very specific on the method. An array is a possibility, but not always suitable. Why don't you post the method in full, or at least the signature and describe (in detail) what the individual parameters do, and what the method does of course! **Edit**: "How?" By expanding your question so we can help ;)

Comment: @thom I recommend you reading "Refactoring", it can answer many questions on how to make the method simpler. I've posted below one of the techniques, google for it to see examples.

Comment: Ah, I can't downvote a commentary. Only upvote - it's wrong. So, Marc B, -1 for your comment.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really clarify a lot to me, I had hoped for a more detailed explanation, also some real code and the *real* method signature, not only hinted at by `...`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Darhazer** and **Zanathel** already gave good answers, and I just want to show you one thing: setters with fluent interface. Only when all parameters are optional.

```
$finder->
 setName($name)->
 setAge($age)->
 setFoo($foo)->
 setBar($bar)->
 setLorem($lorem)->
 search();
```

or

```
$query = new SearchQuery($required_argument);
$query->setAge($optional)->setLorem($optional);

$finder->search($query);
```

to create [fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html), just write in setter's body `return $this;`

Answer (score 6):

I like using arrays for functions that might/have many parameters.  This sort of approach allows for near infinite expansion of parameters, and is more straightforward and better than using something like `func_get_args()`.

```
public function search(array $options = array())
{
    $defaults = array(
        'name'   => null,
        'age'    => null,
        'order'  => null,
        'limit'  => null,
        'offset' => null,
    );
    $options = array_merge($defaults, $options);

    extract($options);

    $select = $this->select();

    if (!is_null($name)) {
        $select->where('name = ?', $name);
    }
    if (!is_null($age)) {
        $select->where('age = ?', $age, Zend_Db::INT_TYPE);
    }
    if (!is_null($order)) {
        $select->order($order);
    }
    if (!is_null($limit) || !is_null($offset)) {
        $select->limit($limit, $offset);
    }

    $results = $this->fetchAll($select);

    return $results;
}
```

...or you can use an object oriented approach:

```
class SearchQuery
{
    public function __construct(array $options = null)
    {
        if (!is_array($options)) {
            return;
        }

        if (array_key_exists('name', $options)) {
            $this->setName($options['name']);
        }
        if (array_key_exists('age', $options)) {
            $this->setAge($options['age']);
        }
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        if (!is_string($name)) {
            throw InvalidArgumentException('$name must be a string');
        }

        $this->_name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setAge($age)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($age) || $age <= 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('$age must be a positive integer');
        }

        $this->_age = $age;

        return $this;
    }
}

// then you can use dependency injection in your main search class

class SearchService
{
    public function search(SearchQuery $query)
    {
        // search
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pack things into a key=>value based array

Example:

```
$params = array("Name"=>"Bob", "Age"=32.....);
Class->search($params);
public function search($params) {
    // access keys
}
```

This is a little bit weary because the method could be used incorrectly very easily since any array could be passed in. Some validation may be required in some other method call to verify the arrays contents.

Edit:  Since there has been some debate in the comments.... here is another way to do this

Create a new class! A user class that contains name age and such and whatever other demographics. You'll probably use those in other places anyway.

Pass the object or objects in as arguments

```
$object = new Object();
SearchClass->search($object)

public function search(Object $object){
     // Do junk here
}
```

Comment: You can always pass any arguments to a method... having an array does not make it easier to use it "incorrectly".

Comment: This one is ok for optional parameters, but in my opinion it's not suitable for required parameters, as you have to check the body of the method to see what were the required keys. Also, it makes body longer, as you have to check if the given parameter was passed or not (and to provide the default values)

Comment: @phant0m If you have a defined set of REQUIRED parameters in a function then you know that it requires those parameters.  By using an array, you can pass in an incorrect number of parameters that the function may require to perform correctly. Like I said, you will have to create a validation method of said required parameters so you can throw an exception if they are incorrect. Therefore, it is easier to misuse. Especially if a client is using the code and is unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @Darhazer I agree. This makes for some rough code and likely some debugging issues in the future. Required parameters should be passed in seperatly.

Comment: It's not only bad because you don't know which arguments are optional and which are not. It's bad because you have to keep in memory all names and datatypes of fields of that array(!), *and* because IDE will not be able to give you autocomplete-suggestions.

Comment: @trevor: True, but PHP will only issue a warning, whereas accessing an array via an undefined index will trigger a Notice, I guess, but the call will succeed in both instances.

Comment: Yes, but as indicated by @OZ_, it is much more suitable for optional arguments.

Comment: @Trevor, passing `array of parameters` it's always bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

[Introduce Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html)

Comment: Already -2 (and mine +1). @Darhazer, your answer is only one which is correct, but, maybe, you can write something more than 3 words in a link? :)

Comment: @OZ_, when parameters are $foo, $bar and $lorem is hard to explain how to refactor them ;) You know - the question contains half of the answer, or the answer is in the same quality as the question. Anyway, thanks for the critics, I agree that some explanation would be useful in order to motivate the reader to read more about this refactoring :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the closest simile to [value objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), where you pass *one* object that contains all the necessary parameters as properties to the function.

```
<?php
class FilterVO {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    // etc ...
}

class SomeCollection {
    public function FilterResults(FilterVO $prefs) {
        // got all the goodies in here
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Instead of check $prefs, you could do something like: public function FilterResults(FilterVO $prefs) ... Thanks.

Comment: it's good when author of the question corrects the answers :)

Comment: Hehe, giving and taking! :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make it so that it accepts an array as parameter with many name-value pairs. Then you can use `extract($paramsArray)` to make all names in array as $variables.